# Python: alternate to brentq and fsolve in python that finds all the zeros of the given function

Tags: python, optimization, solver

Is there a module that will find all the zeros of function instead of the first zero it encounters beyond a specified starting point?

With `brentq`, we would specify where the function changes sign and only pick up that location unless with did this `n` times.  Similarly, with `fsolve`, we pick a starting point and then it finds the first zero beyond that point and again we would have to do that `n` times.  How could I find all `n` locations in one calling where `n < infinity` of course.

The function I have in mind as 3 zeros and is below:

```
import numpy as np
import pylab
from scipy.optimize import brentq

mm = 7.3477e22  #  mass moon                                                        
me = 5.9736e24  #  mass Earth                                                       
r12 = 384400.0  #  distance between the Earth and the moon                          
pi2 = mm / (me + mm)


def f(xi):
    return ((1.0 - pi2) / np.absolute(xi - pi2) ** 3.0 * (xi + pi2) +
            pi2 / np.absolute(xi + pi2 - 1.0) ** 3.0 * (xi + pi2 - 1.0) - xi)
```